# Story about below-average intelligence guy getting smart getting into conflict with his employer

Tags: story-identification

In the story, a guy with average or below-average intelligence gets a treatment that raises his intelligence considerably.

Then there was some sort of a conflict, possibly a blackmailing or trying to gain control of his employer. Maybe an accountant in a crime family, trying to become the boss?
I can't remember the details clearly.

> I think he might have failed, possibly got betrayed by his wife, who was cheating on him with one of the bad guys?

I read it in 2010s, in English, but most likely it was much older work. I don't believe it was longer than a short story or a novelette.

For some reason I used to think it was by Alfred Bester, but I couldn't find anything by him like this in my library.

I have already ruled out: *Understand* by Ted Chiang, *Flowers for Algernon* by Daniel Keyes

Comment: Hi, I'm not entirely sure, but I don't believe it was a full-length novel. Possibly a novelette or just a short story

Comment: Not submitting this as an answer but Asimov's "Lest we Remember" has some similarities only it's not an intelligence boost but, rather, giving him an absolutely perfect memory.  http://www.asimovreviews.net/Stories/Story145.html  I don't think the wife has an affair with anybody but his career is jeopardized.

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt that's probably it! Seems I'd also need some boost to my memory

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt that's definitely it! I have read it in _Robot Dreams_ collection. Thank you, I'll mark your answer as soon as it's possible

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt - it sounds as though you should indeed submit your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: The question made me think of *The Speed of Dark* by Elizabeth Moon, although there are some significant mismatches. But since a match has been identified, I only post this as a somewhat similar work that might interest the OP and others who read this thread.

Comment: Accidentally many details match "[Flowers for Algernon](https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v016n04_1959-04_PDF/page/n3/mode/2up?view=theater)" (but some don't).

Comment: A couple of elements (increased intelligence, issues at work) could also match *Hurricane Trio* by Theodore Sturgeon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the conversation above, I'm answering with "Lest we Remember" by Isaac Asimov.  The giveaway, to me, was the work/conflict angle with the wife playing a prominent role.  There wasn't, at least to my recollection any kind of organized crime aspect, just your typical corporate intrigue.

Comment: Can you include the information (from comments or otherwise) that makes you think this is the correct answer?